# Does GetMovieAudioVolumeLevels() support more than two channels of audio?

Tags: macos, audio, quicktime

I have some code that uses GetMovieAudioVolumeLevels() to get levels of a QuickTime movie during playback.

I have an 8 audio channel QuickTime movie, but using the GetMovieAudioVolumeLevels() call it only ever returns 2 channels. I am using kQTAudioMeter_DeviceMix, and right now I'm assuming because my MacPro can only actually playback 2 channels of audio (left and right) QuickTime is mixing the 8 channels down to 2 channels.

Does anyone have any more experience with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that "[channels are automatically mixed-down as needed (when playing multichannel sound through a stereo output, for example).](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/RM/MovieBasics/MTOpenPlayMovies/3openplaymovies_output/chapter_1000_section_6.html)"

Does [SGGetChannelVolume](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTRef_SequenceGrabber/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SGGetChannelVolume) do what you need?